# Can't inner join onto embedded query

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm using the northwind compact edition database, and I'm trying to extract which sales persons has earned how much.

So, the inner parts of my query work fine, in that I get a list of employee ids with total cost:

```
select orderCosts."Employee ID", sum(orderCosts.Cost) as OrderCost from
   (
       select Orders."Order Id",orders."Employee ID", orders."Customer ID", "Order Details"."Unit Price" * "Order Details"."Quantity" as Cost from orders
       inner join "Order Details"
       On Orders."Order ID" = "Order Details"."Order ID"
   ) orderCosts
   group by ordercosts."Employee ID"
```

What I thought was ok, I'll then try to join that onto the employee table, which doesn't seem that complicated, but now I'm getting a `"The table aliases must be unique. [Name of duplicate alias = employeePerformance]"` error. I embedded and named the table, seemingly as I have before, like so:

```
select Employees."FirstName", Employees."LastName", employeePerformance.OrderCost
from
(
   select orderCosts."Employee ID", sum(orderCosts.Cost) as OrderCost from
   (
       select Orders."Order Id",orders."Employee ID", orders."Customer ID", "Order Details"."Unit Price" * "Order Details"."Quantity" as Cost from orders
       inner join "Order Details"
       On Orders."Order ID" = "Order Details"."Order ID"
   ) orderCosts
   group by ordercosts."Employee ID"
) employeePerformance
inner join employeePerformance
On Emplyees."Employee ID" = employeePerformance."Employee ID"
```

I can see that I'm only declaring empployeePerformance once, and then trying to inner join onto it, so why does it think I've got it twice?

I'm quite new to SQL, so please be kind if I'm doing something daft!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add a FROM on employees, an join on the subquery (if I understood well)

```
select Employees."FirstName", Employees."LastName", employeePerformance.OrderCost
from Employees
INNER JOIN
(
   select orderCosts."Employee ID", sum(orderCosts.Cost) as OrderCost from
   (
       select Orders."Order Id",orders."Employee ID", orders."Customer ID", "Order Details"."Unit Price" * "Order Details"."Quantity" as Cost from orders
       inner join "Order Details"
       On Orders."Order ID" = "Order Details"."Order ID"
   ) orderCosts
   group by ordercosts."Employee ID"
) employeePerformance

On Employees."Employee ID" = employeePerformance."Employee ID"
```

cause in your query, you make FROM on employeesPerformance and inner join on employeesperformance => duplicate name, which is not permitted.

By the way, your query could be widely simplified, I think :

```
SELECT e."FirstName", e."LastName", sum(od."Unit Price" * od."Quantity") as OrderCosts
FROM employees e
inner join orders o on o."Employee ID" = e."Employee ID"
inner join "Order Details" od on od."Order ID" = o."Order ID"
group by e."Employee ID", e."FirstName", e."LastName"
```

use left joins instead of inner join (and coalesce on unit price and quantity) if you want employees without orders / order details.

```
SELECT e."FirstName", e."LastName", sum(coalesce(od."Unit Price", 0) * coalesce(od."Quantity", 0)) as OrderCosts
FROM employees e
left join orders o on o."Employee ID" = e."Employee ID"
left join "Order Details" od on od."Order ID" = o."Order ID"
group by e."Employee ID", e."FirstName", e."LastName"
```

Comment: I think I understand; It looks like I got the syntax wrong, and in effect, was trying to join the table onto itself?

Comment: @ImmortalBlue well yes (it was not a table but an aliased subquery, but the effect is the same.